# Failing to install glmnet package in R studio

Tags: r

I get the error below when I try to run `install.packages('glmnet', dependencies=TRUE)`. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Francis Jingo/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
glmnet  4.1-1  4.1-2              TRUE

installing the source package ‘glmnet’

trying URL 'https://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/glmnet_4.1-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 2184440 bytes (2.1 MB)
downloaded 2.1 MB

* installing *source* package 'glmnet' ...
** package 'glmnet' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
"C:/RBuildTools/4.0/mingw32/bin/"gfortran  -fno-optimize-sibling-calls    -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c glmnet5dpclean.f -o glmnet5dpclean.o
"C:/RBuildTools/4.0/mingw32/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c glmnet_init.c -o glmnet_init.o
"C:/RBuildTools/4.0/mingw32/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c pb.c -o pb.o
"C:/RBuildTools/4.0/mingw32/bin/"gfortran  -fno-optimize-sibling-calls    -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c wls.f -o wls.o
      0 [main] basename (22752) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\basename.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180347408/0x18034C408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      0 [main] basename (26300) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\basename.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180347408/0x18034C408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      1 [main] basename (23852) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\basename.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180347408/0x18034C408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      0 [main] sed (24408) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sed.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180347408/0x18034C408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      0 [main] sed (23912) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sed.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180347408/0x18034C408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
C:/RBuildTools/4.0/mingw32/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o glmnet.dll tmp.def glmnet5dpclean.o glmnet_init.o pb.o wls.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/bin/i386 -lR
      0 [main] rm (26552) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\rm.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180347408/0x18034C408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk:13: glmnet.dll] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'glmnet'
* removing 'C:/Users/Francis Jingo/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/glmnet'
```

Comment: Try `install.packages('gelmnet', dependencies=TRUE, type="binary")`

Comment: *** I get this***
> install.packages('gelmnet', dependencies=TRUE, type="binary")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Francis Jingo/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gelmnet’ is not available as a binary package for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
>

Comment: Oops, I copied your first command which seems to have a typo in the package name. Try `install.packages('glmnet', dependencies=TRUE, type="binary")`

Comment: This works, thank you very much .